# Logstash filter: aggregate nested arrays

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-jdbc

I'm trying to fetch data from MySQL and push it to `ElasticSearch` using `Logstash` and I'm having trouble creating a config file for `Logstash` that suits my need

I'm **trying to achieve** this result:

```
{
   "products":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "deals":[
            {
               "id":5,
               "options":[
                  {
                     "id":3
                  },
                  {
                     "id":8
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

In MySQL, each of these has its own table, meaning that

Product -> Deal `(ONE => MANY)` |
Deal -> Deal Option`(ONE => MANY)`

To combine them all, I have a MySQL View that would `LEFT JOIN` those tables so I can process everything using LogStash

Here is my current `LogStash Configuration`

```
filter {
  aggregate {
    task_id => "%{id}"
    code => "
    map['id'] ||= event.get('id')

    map['deals'] ||= []    
    map['deals'] << {'id' => event.get('deal_id')}


    event.cancel()
    "
    push_previous_map_as_event => true
    timeout => 15
  }
}
```

Although I got stuck at the part where I need to add `Deal Options` to a `Deal`, is my current `Logstash config` correct? If it is, how can I complete it, thanks for your time!